Ubuntu Firefox How to get uploaded images to display correctly?
Environment: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, AMD GPU, Wayland, Linux 6.11.0-1-t2-noble, AMD Radeon™ RX 6800 XT, Firefox 130.0.1 (64-bit), .deb install.
Below for example uploading images in Firefox on ebay when listing something looks like this, vertical stripes, no image. Uploading the same images using Google Chrome flatpak install, works just fine.

Also for example I am logged into Firefox Sync Account and within my profile icon there are vertical stripes instead of an image (see second round image from the left that is pink):


I am not allowed to answer since my ability to answer has been erroneously blocked so I have to provide the answer in a comment: That has been bugging me for years, figured it out thanks to:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1322787
about:config set
privacy.resistFingerprinting.autoDeclineNoUserInputCanvasPrompts
to false instead of true
this will pop up whether you want to resist fingerprinting on the canvas and you can allow it and the uploaded image with now show.
